# kubectl unable to recognize "dashboard/deployment.yml"

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am getting the following error when i try to deploy a kubernetes service using my bitbucket pipeline to my kubernetes cluster. I am using [deploying services](https://github.com/hobby-kube/guide#deploying-services) method to deploy the service which works fine on my local machine so i am not able to reproduce the issue.

Is it a certificate issue or some configuration issue ?

How can i resolve this ?

```
1s
+ kubectl apply -f dashboard/
unable to recognize "dashboard/deployment.yml": Get https://kube1.mywebsitedomain.com:6443/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate is valid for kube1, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not kube1.mywebsitedomain.com
unable to recognize "dashboard/ingress.yml": Get https://kube1.mywebsitedomain.com:6443/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate is valid for kube1, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not kube1.mywebsitedomain.com
unable to recognize "dashboard/secret.yml": Get https://kube1.mywebsitedomain.com:6443/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate is valid for kube1, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not kube1.mywebsitedomain.com
unable to recognize "dashboard/service.yml": Get https://kube1.mywebsitedomain.com:6443/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate is valid for kube1, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not kube1.mywebsitedomain.com
```

Before running the apply command I did set the cluster using the kubectl config and i get the following on the console.

```
+ kubectl config set-cluster kubernetes --server=https://kube1.mywebsitedomain.com:6443
Cluster "kubernetes" set.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the certificate issue. Using the right certificate will definitely solve this problem but in my case the certificate verification wasn't necessary as secure connection is not required for this spike.

So here is my work around

I used the flag `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` with kubectl and it worked fine

```
+ kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify apply -f dashboard/
deployment.extensions/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
ingress.extensions/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-auth unchanged
service/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
```